# How to check if an image attachment exists before uploading

Tags: uploads, attachments

I'm trying to programatically upload images to WP checking if an image of the same name already exists. I'm doing this from within a plugin, in the admin panel via `add_submenu_page()`.

I use a `foreach()` to upload 2 images per post, and I give them a name based on my post's slug, but only one of them is correctly found in WP and omitted, the other one is always re-uploaded to WP even if it exists.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// sample vars
$slug = 'my-post-slug';
$card['img'] = 'http://example.com/img1.jpg';
$card['imgGold'] = 'http://example.com/img2.jpg';
// end sample vars

$images = '';
$images[] = $card['img'];
$images[] = $card['imgGold'];
foreach ( $images as $url ) {

    // check if current url is for regular or gold image
    if ( $card['imgGold'] == $url ) {
        $desc = $slug .'-gold';
    } else {
        $desc = $slug;
    }

    // check if attachment already exists
    $attachment_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'name'           => $desc
    );
    $attachment_check = new Wp_Query( $attachment_args );

    // if attachment exists, reuse and update data
    if ( $attachment_check->have_posts() ) {

        echo 'Attachment <strong>'. $desc .'</strong> found, omitting download...<br>';

        // do stuff..

    // if attachment doesn't exist fetch it from url and save it
    } else {

        echo 'Attachment <strong>'. $desc .'</strong> not found, downloading...<br>';

        // handle image upload from url and assign to post
        $src = media_sideload_image( $url, $post_id, $desc, 'src' );

        // add post meta
        if ( $card['imgGold'] == $url  ) {
            add_post_meta( $post_id, 'imgGold', $src );
        } else {
            add_post_meta( $post_id, 'img', $src );
        }

    } // end attachment exists

} // end foreach image
```

The gold image is the one that work as intended. The regular one is always re-uploaded. No idea why though, any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I finally found the problem! I was trying to assign the same slug to both the attachment and the parent post, and apparently WordPress won't have that. **The "name" in the media library for the attachment was correct but the actual slug was getting a -2 at the end.**

Here's the fixed code, simply by **making the image slugs unique**:

```
// sample vars
$slug = 'my-post-slug';
$card['img'] = 'http://example.com/img1.jpg';
$card['imgGold'] = 'http://example.com/img2.jpg';
// end sample vars

$images = '';
$images[] = $card['img'];
$images[] = $card['imgGold'];
foreach ( $images as $url ) {

    // check if current url is for regular or gold image
    if ( $card['imgGold'] == $url ) {
        $desc = $slug .'-img-gold';
    } else {
        $desc = $slug .'-img';
    }

    // check if attachment already exists
    $attachment_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'name'           => $desc
    );
    $attachment_check = new Wp_Query( $attachment_args );

    // if attachment exists, reuse and update data
    if ( $attachment_check->have_posts() ) {

        echo 'Attachment <strong>'. $desc .'</strong> found, omitting download...<br>';

        // do stuff..

    // if attachment doesn't exist fetch it from url and save it
    } else {

        echo 'Attachment <strong>'. $desc .'</strong> not found, downloading...<br>';

        // handle image upload from url and assign to post
        $src = media_sideload_image( $url, $post_id, $desc, 'src' );

        // add post meta
        if ( $card['imgGold'] == $url  ) {
            add_post_meta( $post_id, 'imgGold', $src );
        } else {
            add_post_meta( $post_id, 'img', $src );
        }

    } // end attachment exists

} // end foreach image
```